# Memory layout for nested structure in c

Tags: c, structure

I understand the structure's concept in C. I also understand how the structure is stored in memory. So I have created follwoing stuff:

```
  struct tag1 {
      char a;
      int b;
  }var1;
```

The size of the structure is 8 bytes(in gcc).

Memory layout example.

```
 -----------
|  |  |  |  | ---> char a (only 1 byte is used and remaining 3 bytes are padding)
 -----------
|  |  |  |  | ---> int b (4 byte is used)
 -----------
```

Now i have some doubt in this sample program. How the nested structure is    stored in memory.

```
  struct tag1{
      int a;
      struct tag2{
          long b;
      }var1;
  }var2;
```

Comment: You can use the `offsetof()` macro in a test program to see how the compiler layouts various structures.  Note that the specific details  technically are implementation dependent. For example, you may see differences depending on whether `long` is a 64 bit type or a 32-bit type.

Comment: `var1` is just another member inside the structure `tag1`., and is just like `a` in the same structure. That `var1` is a structure doesn't really matter. So of you want to do a "memory layout example" for the second example with the nested structure, just place the nested structure where `var1` is just like you placed `b` in the first example, with the difference being that you have `long var1.b` instead.

Comment: Just apply the rules recursively.

Comment: Thank you sir. The size of the structure is 16 bytes in gcc. Explain me sir.

Comment: The size of the struct includes the size of each member _and_ alignment padding.  and as implied in other comments, padding can be affected by how you set up your compiler.  (with pragma pack macro)

Answer (score 6):

As noted in comments, the exact layout of a struct in memory is implementation specific.  Also generally true, layout is affected by member types, memory addressing (32bit or 64bit) and `pragma pack` calls that adjust the way alignment occurs along memory boundaries.

***An example*** of what I see on my system when I place two instances of your original struct as sub-struct members into yet another struct (for context, and to force contiguous memory assignment), then assigned values to an instance of that struct to provide distinguishable (non-zero) content in the memory layout:
(32bit addressing, with no pragma statements)

```
typedef struct tag1{
      int a;
      struct tag2{
          long b;
      }var1;
}var2;

typedef struct {
    var2 s1;
    var2 s2;
}S;
```

In main:

```
 S x = {0};

  x.s1.a = 1;
  x.s1.var1.b = 2;
  x.s2.a = 3;
  x.s2.var1.b = 4;
```

Memory for `struct S` depicted on first line of image:

[image]

Note there is no additional memory usage required *directly* due to the struct or even sub-struct constructs. But *indirectly*, there can be (and often will be) additional memory required for *[alignment padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)*.  This occurs when data types contained in the struct definition are of differing sizes and do not align naturally along addressing boundaries.  When this occurs, padding *will* effect the computed `sizeof` a `struct`.

You can see that the size of each instance of your original struct is 8, (16 for two instances) and because `int` and `long` both align perfectly (and are the same size) in this instance, there appears to be no padding.  If`long` were replaced with `long long` this would no longer be the case.  Padding would almost certainly be required.

To provide context for the information below, relevant data sizes on my machine (compiled for 32bit) are:

```
int sizeChar = sizeof(char);     //1 (always)
int sizeInt  = sizeof(int);      //4
int sizeLong = sizeof(long);     //4
int sizeLL   = sizeof(long long);//8
```

There will be more visible evidence of padding and the effects of pragma using a wider range of types.  The following struct contains 4 data types:

```
 typedef struct tag1 {
      char a;
      int b;
      long c;
      long long d;
  }var1;
```

Using this struct definition, it is interesting to view the difference in padding caused by using `pragma pack` calls.  On my machine, and compiling for 32bit memory mapping, here is what I see:

[image]

By the way, there is a discussion *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26568630/645128)* covering related points in this topic.

Answer (score 2):

**How the nested structure is stored in memory?**

```
struct tag1{
      int a;
      struct tag2{
          long b;
      }var1;
  }var2;
```

First of all you need to check the machine word size (i.e either 32-bit/64-bit) & on which gcc compiler is installed. Depending upon the architectures, the variables memory allocation will be varying.
**sizeof** operator will return the variables size according to system specific.

For example(with padding) variables stored in memory

in 32-bit machines int & long both are allocating 4-bytes.

|var2.var1.b|==>0x601058

|   var2.a  |==>0x601054

in 64-bit machines int allocates 4-bytes & long allocates 8-bytes.

|var2.var1.b|==>0x601058

|   var2.a  |==>0x601050

Memory alignment of structure members is explained here [Alignment in c](https://wr.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/_media/teaching/wintersemester_2013_2014/epc-14-haase-svenhendrik-alignmentinc-paper.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

To figure out how the nested structure is stored in memory, you can run the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct tag1{
    int a;
    struct tag2{
        long b;
    } var1;
} var2;

int main(void){
    printf("CHAR_BIT is\t\t\t\t%d\n", CHAR_BIT);
    puts("");
    printf("sizeof var2 is\t\t\t\t%zu\n", sizeof var2);
    printf("sizeof var2.var1 is\t\t\t%zu\n", sizeof var2.var1);
    printf("sizeof var2.var1.b is\t\t\t%zu\n", sizeof var2.var1.b);
    puts("");
    printf("offsetof(struct tag1, a) is\t\t%zu\n", offsetof(struct tag1, a));
    printf("offsetof(struct tag1, var1) is\t\t%zu\n", offsetof(struct tag1, var1));
    printf("offsetof(struct tag1, var1.b) is\t%zu\n", offsetof(struct tag1, var1.b));
    printf("offsetof(struct tag2, b) is\t\t%zu\n", offsetof(struct tag2, b));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm asking you to run this code on your implementation, rather than giving you an direct answer, because:

1. sizeof T is implementation-define. What if you have `sizeof (long) == 1` and `CHAR_BIT == 32`?
2. There might be padding bits/bytes in a struct.
3. Other factors. For example, the use of `#pragma pack(n)`

On my implementation (clang under OS X), the output is:

```
CHAR_BIT is             8

sizeof var2 is              16
sizeof var2.var1 is         8
sizeof var2.var1.b is           8

offsetof(struct tag1, a) is     0
offsetof(struct tag1, var1) is      8
offsetof(struct tag1, var1.b) is    8
offsetof(struct tag2, b) is     0
```

Well, it does not seem neat here, but it's nicely-formatted when showing up on my screen.

So (for my implementation) the memory layout of `struct tag1` will be like this:

```
 -----------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ---> int a (8 bytes are used)
 -----------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ---> struct tag2 / long b (8 bytes are used)
 -----------------------
```